# TextField Corner Radius : Not Sharp Corners

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, calayer

I am trying to add corner radius on uitextfield effect applies but not sharp corner.

Please check attached pictures.[image]

I am expecting result like this. [image]

Here is my Code for gray textfield.

```
 self.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
 self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
 self.layer.borderColor =  UIColor(red: 209/255.0, green: 209/255.0, blue: 209/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor 
 self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Here is my Code for Red textfield.

```
 self.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
 self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
 self.layer.borderColor = TextFieldRedBorderColor.CGColor
 self.backgroundColor = TextFieldRedBackgroundColor
```

There is only color difference between both code but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was just one mistake in my code.

TextField Border Style Was Line

```
textField.borderStyle = .Line
```

then I make it None

```
textField.borderStyle = .None
```

and it work like I wanted (Rounded Corners)...

Anyway.. Thanks for support and answers...

Answer (score 3):

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

This will solves your issue

Answer (score 2):

```
 @IBOutlet var passwordboarderview: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var textusername: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet var txtpassword: UITextField!

 passwordboarderview.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
 passwordboarderview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
 passwordboarderview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

 passwordboarderview.clipsToBounds = true
 txtpassword.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Password",attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])   

 let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
 textusername.leftView = paddingView
 textusername.leftViewMode = .Always
 textusername.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
 textusername.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5
 textusername.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
 textusername.clipsToBounds = true
```

**Output** :

[image: Here is output.]

**Storyboard**:

[image: Here is storyboard .]

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  FDTextField.swift
//  FilloutDocs
//
//  Created by Janak Thakkar on 15/03/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 zetrixweb. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private var maxLengthDictionary = [UITextField : Int]()

@IBDesignable

class ZWTextField : UITextField {

    var topBorder: UIView?
    var bottomBorder: UIView?
    var leftBorder: UIView?
    var rightBorder: UIView?
    var leftimageview : UIImageView?
    var rightimageview : UIImageView?
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var ULText: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, (self.text?.characters.count)!)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (self.text)!)
            attributedText.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName , value:NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue, range: textRange)
            // Add other attributes if needed

            self.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fitToWidth: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = fitToWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var cursorColor : UIColor = UIColor.blueColor(){
        didSet {
            tintColor = cursorColor
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var placeHolderColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor(){
        didSet {
            setValue(placeHolderColor, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor")
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
    @IBInspectable var rightImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if rightImage != nil {
                let width = rightviewWidth > rightImage!.size.width + 10 ? rightviewWidth :  rightImage!.size.width + 10
                rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
                rightimageview = UIImageView()
                rightimageview!.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - width, self.frame.origin.y+2, width,self.frame.size.height-4)
                rightimageview!.image = rightImage
                rightView = rightimageview
                self.rightViewMode = .Always
                rightimageview!.contentMode = .Center
            }
            else {
                if rightimageview != nil {
                    rightimageview?.removeFromSuperview()
                    rightimageview = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var rightviewWidth : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if rightimageview != nil{
                let width = rightviewWidth > rightImage!.size.width + 10 ? rightviewWidth :  rightImage!.size.width + 10
                rightimageview!.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+5, self.frame.origin.y+2, width,self.frame.size.height-4)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var leftImage : UIImage? {
        didSet {
            if leftImage != nil {
                let width = leftviewWidth > leftImage!.size.width + 10 ? leftviewWidth :  leftImage!.size.width + 10
                leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
                leftimageview = UIImageView();
                leftimageview!.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+50, self.frame.origin.y+5, width,self.frame.size.height-5)
                //leftimageview!.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 40, 40)
                leftimageview!.image = leftImage;
                leftView = leftimageview;
                self.leftViewMode = .Always
                leftimageview!.contentMode = .Center
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var leftviewWidth : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if leftimageview != nil{
                let width = leftviewWidth > leftImage!.size.width + 10 ? leftviewWidth :  leftImage!.size.width + 10
                leftimageview!.frame=CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x+5, self.frame.origin.y+2, width,self.frame.size.height-4)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomLineWidth : CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet{
            let border: CALayer = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - bottomLineWidth, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
            border.borderWidth = borderWidth
            self.layer.addSublayer(border)
            self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var bottomLineColor : UIColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor(){
        didSet {
            let border: CALayer = CALayer()
            border.borderColor = bottomLineColor.CGColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var paddingLeft: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable var paddingRight: CGFloat = 0

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + paddingLeft, bounds.origin.y,
            bounds.size.width - paddingLeft - paddingRight, bounds.size.height);
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return textRectForBounds(bounds)
    }
    @IBInspectable var topBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    @IBInspectable var topBorderHeight : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if topBorder == nil{
                topBorder = UIView()
                topBorder?.backgroundColor=topBorderColor;
                topBorder?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, topBorderHeight)
                addSubview(topBorder!)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var bottomBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    @IBInspectable var bottomBorderHeight : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if bottomBorder == nil{
                bottomBorder = UIView()
                bottomBorder?.backgroundColor=bottomBorderColor;
                bottomBorder?.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - bottomBorderHeight, self.frame.size.width, bottomBorderHeight)
                addSubview(bottomBorder!)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var leftBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    @IBInspectable var leftBorderHeight : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if leftBorder == nil{
                leftBorder = UIView()
                leftBorder?.backgroundColor=leftBorderColor;
                leftBorder?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, leftBorderHeight, self.frame.size.height)
                addSubview(leftBorder!)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var rightBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    @IBInspectable var rightBorderHeight : CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet{
            if rightBorder == nil{
                rightBorder = UIView()
                rightBorder?.backgroundColor=topBorderColor;
                rightBorder?.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - rightBorderHeight, 0, rightBorderHeight, self.frame.size.height)
                addSubview(rightBorder!)
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
        get {
            if let length = maxLengthDictionary[self] {
                return length
            } else {
                return Int.max
            }
        }
        set {
            maxLengthDictionary[self] = newValue
            addTarget(self, action: "checkMaxLength:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
        }
    }

    func checkMaxLength(sender: UITextField) {
        let newText = sender.text
        if newText?.characters.count > maxLength {
            let cursorPosition = selectedTextRange
            text = (newText! as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: maxLength))
            selectedTextRange = cursorPosition
        }
    }


}
```

Just add this file in project and you can set all the properties and can see realtime out.All properties you can set through storyboard.

Comment: Though it might be an interesting code, it adds so much on top that the answer to the question isn't visible.

Comment: I tried to cover all the properties with @IBInspectable , let me know if you still need more.

Comment: Here i have uploaded sample code to github ::: https://github.com/ZetrixWeb-iOS/TextField---IBDesignable